# I have confusion about Dart code in Flutter Framework

Tags: flutter, dart, oop

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('My First App'),
        ),
        body: Text('This is my default text'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have recently started learning the Flutter framework , and it's hell lot on confusing for me , can u please explain the sections of this code above like , what is that **BuildContext**
, the **MaterialApp** (is it a contructor or a class, ? ),
and it's parameters , I tried learning from their docs , but their is just too much its confusing to me , all i know from this code written in this class is that , build method returns a widget , and scaffold is some sort of predefined code which helps with the layout , something like bootstrap helps with CSS

Comment: I will recommend checking on [flutter.dev](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/codelab) and some google search for startup, Everything has first time, be patient and focus, you can find many good videos on YouTube.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at it one line at a time.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
```

In this line you are declaring a class MyApp which extends the Stateless widget class. That means that MyApp will have the functionality of a Stateless widget and the bits of code that you are adding to it.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```

Here you are defining the build method. A Widget needs a build method, that's how flutter knows how to build the widget and show it. The build method receives a BuildContext parameter which is a handle to the location of a widget in the widget tree.

```
    return MaterialApp(
```

The build method returns a MaterialApp widget. In fact, MaterialApp() is the constructor of the MaterialApp widget.

```
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('My First App'),
        ),
        body: Text('This is my default text'),
```

The constructor of MaterialApp has a home and a body parameter. Here you are passing a Scaffold widget to the Home parameter. The Scaffold widget constructor (`Scaffold()`) has an appBar parameter, that receives a Widget (in this case, the Widget is `AppBar`). And the `AppBar` constructor has a title parameter, which receives a `Text` widget. And the body parameter also receives a `Text` widget.

```
      ),
    );
  }
}
```